# UNC path not supported. Shiny app can't be run through a Batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, shiny

I find out a way to run my R Shiny apps with batch files (the problem is in the Plot Twist part).

Three files which make the magic are in the same folder:

1. main.R
2. run.R
3. RunApp.bat

`main.R` is the script which has the shiny App.

`run.R` is a script that runs the `main.R` file and opens in the default browser.

`RunApp.bat` is a script that runs the `run.R` script.

This is the script in `run.R`

```
library(shiny)
script = "main.R"
runApp(script, launch.browser = TRUE)
```

this is the script in `RunApp.bat` with the path where R is in my local machine:

```
"C:\Users\Me\Documents\R\R-4.1.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "run.R"
```

Then, `RunApp.bat` opens my shiny app in the browser in my local machine. This is useful because I can open the webapp with a direct access of the RunApp.bat file located in my desktop or whenever I want and therefore the source code will be hidden by other users.

**Plot twist:**

There are other users I'd like to share the webapp with. We all share a sharedFolder located in a server (I don't know if I'm using the right terms here, I'm just a statistician and don't know much about Informatics), That server is a machine which I have access to.

Then, if the other users have access to the shared folder in their local machines, I just have to place the three Files (mentioned above) in that sharedFolder and through that Batch file run the App.

I did all that and moved the R folder into the sharedFolder. I only changed the `RunApp.bat` script to:

```
"\\192.168.x.y\sharedFolder\R\R-4.1.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "run.R"
```

but when I run the `RunApp.bat` file I got the next message:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. 
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Window directory.

C:Windows>"\\192.168.x.y\sharedFolder\R\R-4.1.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "run.R"
```

also when I run the R.exe file inside the sharedFolder the same "UNC paths not supported" message appears.

Is there something I can do to solve this problem? I searched and find something about using the `PUSHD` and `POPD` commands, but I don't know if I'm using them the right way because it didn't work.

Comment: UNC paths are not supported so you cannot use filepaths like "\\192.168.x.y\sharedFolder" on Windows. You'll need to mount that [UNC path to a local file path](https://superuser.com/questions/244562/how-do-i-mount-a-network-drive-to-a-folder). You'd need to do this for each user that wants to run the application.

Comment: I don't know if I get it right, but does it mean that a sharedfolder is not possible in this situation? I have to set up in every machine the application as I have it in my local machine?

Comment: The [`pushd` command](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) supports UNC paths and maps such to a temporary drive; [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) eventually releases that drive…

Answer (score 0):

`pushd` will assign a drive letter for a network path. Don't forget to `popd` to remove it though.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.